# Replace element contents with document fragment javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, documentfragment

I'm trying to replace all contents of an element with a document fragment:

`var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()`

The document fragment is being created just fine. No problems there. I add elements to it just fine, no problems there either. I can append it using `element.appendChild(frag)`. That works just fine too.

I'm trying to create a "replace" method similar to jQuery's HTML. I'm not worried about old-browser compatibility. Is there a magical function to replace all content of an element?

I have tried `element.innerHTML = frag.cloneNode(true)`, (as per *every* 'replace element content' wiki I could find), that doesn't work. It gives me `<div>[object DocumentFragment]</div>`.

No libraries, please, not even a jQuery solution.

For clarity, I'm looking for a "magic" solution, I know how to remove all the existing elements one at a time and then append my fragment.

Comment: Just curious, why the aversion to libraries?

Comment: Project spec beyond my control. Also, kind of fun to try to do things "old school".

Comment: @pimvdb essentially, yes. But I'd like to do it in one swoop, to avoid page re-draws (I could innerHTML = "" then appendChild, but that's 2 re-draws).

Comment: @Randy Hall: Hm, well, since a fragment only exists at one place at a time, you could replace each child node again and again, so that they are implicitly removed: http://jsfiddle.net/tMGFM/. But I'm not sure if that's what you want - just `element.innerHTML = "";` and then appending should not do a redraw in between.

Comment: @pimvdb that should be an answer, not a comment. It totally works. However, there's two issues still: 1) I'd like an answer without the loop (if possible) and 2) theoretically, the browser redraws each time there's a node change. This will perform a node change for each element I'm replacing. Right direction thought!

Comment: Maybe appending the fragment to a detached element (to avoid a redraw) and then transfering the `innerHTML` is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/tMGFM/1/ Still, I've never seen redraws when manipulating multiple times in a row.

Comment: pimvdb, you are way too fast, but I have the same solution :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried `replaceChild`

something like this

```
element.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, element)
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild

original jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/RxFZA/

EDIT:  ahh, I didn't see replace contents.  Well, just remove them first!

```
element.innerHTML = "";
element.appendChild(frag);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/RxFZA/1/

note that in the jsfiddle, I only use jquery to hook up the button, the entirety of the click handler is raw javascript.

Edit2: also suggested by pimvdb, but just append the new stuff to a detached element and replace.

```
var newElement = element.cloneNode();
newElement.innerHTML = "";
newElement.appendChild(frag);
element.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, element);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/RxFZA/3/

Comment: Not quite, sorry. This replaces the element with the fragment, I need to replace the element's content with the fragment.

Comment: Better! Ideally, I could do it in one go, so as to avoid a browser redraw on `element.innerHTML = ""` - however, this is probably the best solution so far (also suggested by @pimvdb). Still hoping someone has something magic!

Comment: See answer below, very similar to your element clone method but with ranges.

Answer (score 7):

2017:
Try this Magic answer from ContentEditable field and [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range)

```
var range = document.createRange(); // create range selection 
range.selectNodeContents($element); // select all content of the node
range.deleteContents() // maybe there is replace command but i'm not find it
range.insertNode(frag)
```

Comment: update answer . you can delete now your extra comments .for cleaner wall

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (cause my original answer was just plain dumb):

```
var rep = document.createElement("div");
rep.appendChild(frag);
element.innerHTML = rep.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Looks like this strips all elements and only sets the textual contents. Personally, I think all "magical" solutions are a bit... odd. `removeChild`/`appendChild(frag)` should work fine.

Comment: In old IE this will only grab text I believe. However, I'm not worried about anything but the most recent browsers (and mostly just mobile). I'll edit to reflect this in my answer.

Comment: Well, it fails for me on Chrome 23. Just so you know :)

Comment: Nevermind, you're completely correct. It is destroying html elements. -1 to my own answer =/

Comment: if you're going to go with ranges, I'd suggest taking a look at http://code.google.com/p/rangy/ (I know, no libraries).  It normalizes alot of inconsistencies across browsers